# A problem to prove two sets have same number of elements using bijection

Tags: combinatorics, functions, elementary-set-theory

I found a nice [problem](http://mathorg.herokuapp.com/problems/1612) on bijections. Suppose we have six digit numbers from $000000$ to $999999$. Let $A$ be the set such that sum of first three digits is same as the sum of last three digits, and $B$ be the set such that the sum of all digits is $27$. Can we prove that number of elements in $A$ and $B$ are same.

Can someone give a hint, how can we define a map from $A$ to $B$ such that the map is bijective?

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  Can you count either set?

Comment: Note that the site you link to does not suggest that the sets have the same number of elements.

Comment: Yes, but my intuition says that these sets have same number of elements. Because, somehow we need to use bijections.

Comment: Hint: given an element of $A$ (or $B$), suppose you are told what its first 5 digits are. Can you figure out what the last digit must be?

Comment: Yes, we can find the last digit using the properties of set $A$ and $B$. For set $A$ it will be $a_{1}+a_{2}+a_{3}-a_{4}-a_{5}$ and for set $B$, it will be $27- a_{1}-a_{2}-a_{3}-a_{4}-a_{5}$.

Comment: I suggest:  try to prove that the number of three digit strings that sums to $N$ is the same as the number of three digit strings that sums to $27-N$ (Hint:  that's not difficult).

Comment: Yes, we can use stars and bars count formula to prove that both have same number of solutions.